# Practical usage of Unity Child Containers in WebAPI application

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I've read a lot of how to use child containers but I can't implement it in practice in my application. I am using UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver and ASP.NET application internally is calling container.Resolve method.

What I need is to have two different setups of class registrations depending which WebAPI controller I am resolving. I am want to tell - "use that container for resolving ApiControllerA grapth and that container for ApiControllerB graph".

What I want to do is:

```
if(typeof(typeToResolve) == typeof(ApiControllerA))
{
    childContainer1.Resolve(typeToResolve)
}
else(typeof(typeToResolve) == typeof(ApiControllerB))
{
   childContainer2.Resolve(typeToResolve)
}
```

What is the best way to implement this logic in real application?

Thanks.